# Using scrapy to download content and save into a list

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to download the content in this webpage into a list, but I am new to scrapy and the list returns as empty. Can someone help me determine where the error is, or what I should do differently?

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "content_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=170161842&fbclid=IwAR21cibgw6AY4NE8KHyqVFSs71zz0S60mlmB8Bg-4FEIl56JVqorFtlS6N0"]

    def parse(self, response):

        yield response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/article/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/text()').get()

def spider_results():
    from scrapy import signals
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
    from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
    results = []
    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal = signals.item_passed)
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
    return results
```

Comment: Imports should go at the top of the file, by the way. That code isn't a [mcve], right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=170161842&fbclid=IwAR21cibgw6AY4NE8KHyqVFSs71zz0S60mlmB8Bg-4FEIl56JVqorFtlS6N0"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for e in response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/article/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/text()').getall():
            yield {'text': e.strip()}

def spider_results():
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
    print(results)

spider_results()
```

It worked. Lost in lots of output I got this:

```
[{'text': 'Pent brukt 1 år gammelt spisebord selges. Det er et lite merke i lakken i bordplaten, ellers i helt fin stand. Ny pris kr. 4995. Må hentes sentralt på Tromsøya. Stolene følger dessverre ikke med!'}]
```

Comment: Thank you! 
However, when trying with a different URL it does not work:
start_urls = ["https://newsweb.oslobors.no/message/495961"]
response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/text()').getall():

Do you know why, and how to solve this?

Comment: The HTML itself does not contain anything interesting, as it is the case for many modern web app. You can try this in your terminal: `curl https://newsweb.oslobors.no/message/495961` , you'll see what I mean. When you go there with your browser, the content is rendered with javascript. Therefore you won't be able to use a classic scraper to get your results with this kind of page.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to get the information? I have tried using selenium, which is just way too slow when scraping several pages

Comment: Selenium or PhantomJs are ways to do that but as you said they are slow. If you know the URLs of the requested API you can use query them using ˋrequests` for example. You’ll typically get JSON or XML which you have then to parse to get your data. You can use your browser to determine those URLs: in the inspector go to network tab and refresh, you’ll see what resources are retrieved and their URLs. There are other solutions like Splash but never tried them https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but I think you should actually call get, like that:

```
response.xpath('...').get()
```

Without the parentheses you just yield the function get, not the results of get.